# Broken pipe symbol from SQL changing in Linux

Tags: linux, solaris, character-encoding

I am migrating Solaris code to Linux and have problem with broken pipe symbol used inside sql scripts.

There are multiple SQL scripts (and output it produces) with broken pipe symbol (`¦`) which works perfectly fine in Solaris. But Linux converts it into reverse question mark symbol (`¿`). Its viewed something like below in Toad

Linux:

```
string1 := string1 || chr(20) || var || ': ' || nvl(var_val, 'NULL') || '¿' ;
```

Solaris:

```
string1 := string1 || chr(20) || var || ': ' || nvl(var_val, 'NULL') || '¦' ;
```

The most I can come upon is that it might be something to so with the encoding, but not sure if thats the case or about the solution. Any leads would be greatly helpful.

Edited to add version and other details:
Using GNU Linux Version 2.6.32

```
# locale
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=
```

Solaris has almost same values except that LANG is empty

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please include some information on your environment: Linux flavor and version, locale, encoding scheme etc. (cf. the output of `env`) so it is easier to help you find the solution to the problem.

Comment: Check the LANG variables

Comment: @RomeoNinov LANG=C. locale gives the below output
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=

Comment: Set in Solaris LANG=C and check again